# Passing arguments with space to linux service

Tags: python, linux, perl

I have a script that accepts parameters that I'd like to be able to run as a linux service.
There is a symlink to it from /etc/ini.t/deploy to the actual script.

If I run

```
/etc/init.d/deploy --machine NAME --message "Hello World"
```

everything works find and the script receives 4 arguments:

```
      '--machine',
      'NAME',
      '--message',
      'Hello World'
```

On the other hand, if I run it as

```
/sbin/service deploy  --machine NAME --message "Hello World"
```

then the script receives 5 parameters:

```
      '--machine',
      'NAME',
      '--message',
      'Hello',
      'World'
```

The same happens both in Perl and Python, so as I understand it is the "service" that passes the arguments after splitting up on space. What can I do to make this work the same way with "service" as when calling directly?

Comment: Modify `service` to not do that.

Comment: A recommended solution here: http://www.mail-archive.com/nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg29089.html but that did not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem of passing arguments.  Obviously something is not passed verbatim in your context but interpretingly, so to speak.

You can use the workaround of quoting your stuff twice:

```
/sbin/service deploy  --machine NAME --message '"Hello World"'
```

In many cases this solves the issue.

A more general approach is to use the `printf "%q"` of modern `bash`s:

```
/sbin/service deploy  --machine NAME --message "$(printf "%q" "Hello World")"
```

This generates a quoted version of the given string.